# Не создается проект (пустой каталог)

Tags: maven

Думаю скриншот все объяснит .

[image: консоль]

Написано что проект создан, не могу понять почему каталог пуст?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Comment: ......... мимо )